# maxAllowedContentLength ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, telerik

I have the following settings in my web config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true"     targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="92160" executionTimeout="3600" />
  </system.web>

 <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="94371840" />
     </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

They both equate to 90 MB. I am using an asynchronous uploader from telerik to upload the file. I've been testing by uploading 100 MB files to see if the error is being triggered. However, the file uploaded without issue. Can't figure why the error is not being triggered. The issue is probably staring me right in the face. Can anyone figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

In `system.web`

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="90000" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

And in system.webServer

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="90000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

**IMPORTANT** : Both of these values must match and `maxRequestLength` measured in `KiloBytes` where as `maxallowedContentLength` in `Bytes` , so both values are set to `90mb`

**From IIS7**

Or in IIS (7):

> Select the website you want enable to accept large file uploads. In
>   the main window double click 'Request filtering' Select "Edit Feature
>   Settings" Modify the "Maximum allowed content length (bytes)"

Comment: I copied your values exactly into webconfig. I was still able to upload a 100 MB file.

Comment: @pmb88 it should be , did you made a clean build and rerun it?